# How to fill missing values in SataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

After querying a mysql db and building the corresponding data frame, I am left with this:

```
mydata.show

+--+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|id| sport|  var1|  var2|  var3|  var4|  var5|
+--+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 1|soccer|330234|      |      |      |      |
| 2|soccer|  null|  null|  null|  null|  null|
| 3|soccer|330101|      |      |      |      |
| 4|soccer|  null|  null|  null|  null|  null|
| 5|soccer|  null|  null|  null|  null|  null|
| 6|soccer|  null|  null|  null|  null|  null|
| 7|soccer|  null|  null|  null|  null|  null|
| 8|soccer|330024|330401|      |      |      |
| 9|soccer|330055|330106|      |      |      |
|10|soccer|  null|  null|  null|  null|  null|
|11|soccer|390027|      |      |      |      |
|12|soccer|  null|  null|  null|  null|  null|
|13|soccer|330101|      |      |      |      |
|14|soccer|330059|      |      |      |      |
|15|soccer|  null|  null|  null|  null|  null|
|16|soccer|140242|140281|      |      |      |
|17|soccer|330214|      |      |      |      |
|18|soccer|      |      |      |      |      |
|19|soccer|330055|330196|      |      |      |
|20|soccer|210022|      |      |      |      |
+--+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Every var column is a:

```
string (nullable = true)
```

So I'd like to change all the empty rows to a "null", so to be able to treat empty cells and cell with "null" as equal, possibly without leaving the data frame for an RDD...

Comment: Why not just change your comparison code so that it treats them as equal? That way you keep your source data intact and don't waste a lot of time with a needless manipulation.

Comment: If your table structure has this many null values in it, then you've probably designed your table structures incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to do the opposite - replace nulls with empty values (I personally hate nulls...), for which you can use the `coalesce` function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val result = input.withColumn("myCol", coalesce(input("myCol"), lit("")))
```

To do that for multiple columns:

```
val cols = Seq("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5")
val result = cols.foldLeft(input) { case (df, colName) => df.withColumn(colName, coalesce(df(colName), lit(""))) }
```

Comment: If one is fine using DataFrames then this could be done in a more controlled way, something like `df.na.fill("NA", (Seq("A", "B")))` if the column A and B are of String type and `df.na.fill(0.0, (Seq("A", "B")))` if the column A and B are of Integer type

Answer (score 2):

My approach would be to create a list of expressions. In Scala this can be done using a `map`. On the other hand in Python you'd to use a comprehension list.

After that, you should unpack that list inside a `df.select` instruction like in the examples bellow.

Inside the expression, empty strings are replaced with a null value

Scala:

```
val exprs = df.columns.map(x => when(col(x) === '', null).otherwise(col(x)).as(x))
df.select(exprs:_*).show()
```

Python:

```
# Creation of a dummy dataframe:
df = sc.parallelize([("", "19911201", 1, 1, 20.0),
                     ("", "19911201", 2, 1, 20.0),
                     ("hola", "19911201", 2, 1, 20.0),
                     (None, "20111201", 3, 1, 20.0)]).toDF()

df.show()

exprs = [when(col(x) == '', None).otherwise(col(x)).alias(x) 
         for x in df.columns]

df.select(*exprs).show()
```

E.g:

```
+----+--------+---+---+----+
|  _1|      _2| _3| _4|  _5|
+----+--------+---+---+----+
|    |19911201|  1|  1|20.0|
|    |19911201|  2|  1|20.0|
|hola|19911201|  2|  1|20.0|
|null|20111201|  3|  1|20.0|
+----+--------+---+---+----+

+----+--------+---+---+----+
|  _1|      _2| _3| _4|  _5|
+----+--------+---+---+----+
|null|19911201|  1|  1|20.0|
|null|19911201|  2|  1|20.0|
|hola|19911201|  2|  1|20.0|
|null|20111201|  3|  1|20.0|
+----+--------+---+---+----+
```